# Set order acs and no paging for archive page

Tags: pages, archives

My code theme archive.php is

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php
/* Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
 */
get_template_part( 'content', 'test' get_post_format() );
?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php semplicemente_paging_nav(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So i want to change order from desc to acs , orderby date and post per page is 100.

I found it.

```
$args = ( array(
'order' => 'ASC',
'orderby' => 'date',
'posts_per_page' => '100',) );
```

So i put $args to get_post_format(), the_post() put nothing happen?

Any idea?

Thank for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks for your help. Now i pay more attention to functions.php so my old code have effectively.

```
/* Change page order */
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts' , 'my_change_order' );

function my_change_order( $query ) {

// Check if the query is for an archive

if($query->is_archive)

    // Query was for archive, then set order

    $query->set( 'order' , 'asc' );


// Return the query (else there's no more query, oops!)

return $query;

}
// Code no paging//
function no_nopaging($query) {
    if (is_date()) {
    $query->set('nopaging', 1);
    }
}

add_action('parse_query', 'no_nopaging');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Changing_the_number_of_posts_per_page.2C_by_post_type) in your functions file for this with the [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) order and orderby parameters.

```
function alter_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin()) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 100 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'alter_query' );
```

Comment: Remember to check for `!is_admin()`. And you want to maybe check for date archives, `is_date()`. Remember, `is_archive()` returns true on category, taxonomy, author and tag pages